# Postgres 'UPDATE' query producing out of memory error

Tags: sql, postgresql, out-of-memory, relational-database

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public.organization
(
 id_organization SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
 name varchar, 
 country varchar,
 prod_id varchar
 );


CREATE TABLE public suborganization
(
 id_suborganization SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
 id_organization bigint references organization(id_organization) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
 full_address varchar,
 prod_id varchar
 );
```

Both tables are populated apart from the suborganization.id_organization. I'm trying to populate this column using the following statement:

```
UPDATE suborganization SET id_organization = organization.id_organization 
FROM organization 
WHERE suborganization.prod_id = organization.prod_id;
```

However, Postgres is producing the following error message and failing to populate the foreign key:

```
ERROR: out of memory
DETAIL: Failed on request of size 8
```

These are large tables, approximately 200 million rows but I'm running it on a machine with 62.8GB of RAM and work_mem set to 4MB.

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this error message? Is it simply a hardware issue or do I need to reconfigure postgres? Or is it my method that is flawed, is there a better way to create this foreign key?

PotgreSQL 9.4.7 running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 6.7

Comment: 1) what is the cardinality of `prod_id` (in both tables) ? It could be that you are updating the same target rows repeatedly. 2) always add a `WHERE suborganisation.id_organization <> organization.id_organization` clause to update-queries to avoid *same valued* updates.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the `on update cascade` option which is essentially done through an "after" trigger.

The list of rows for which the trigger needs to be fired is kept in memory and that is what is eating up the memory.

Try removing the `cascade` options for the FK constraint. Or do the update in batches of e.g. a million.

Comment: Great, I'll give it a try and get back to you. Is there a way to drop the 'on update cascade' without dropping and recreating the table?

Comment: @matt: just drop and re-create the foreign key.